# Dissolving Polystyrene with D-Limonene

Tags: solubility, polymers, hydrocarbons

I have a product, which according to the MSDS is mostly D-Limonene. I don't have the means to chemically test it, but I did try dissolving polystyrene with it. Before I come check it again, should I expect how polystyrene "dissolves" in acetone? As a goop at the bottom, even as I add much excess acetone? Or, should I see it truly dissolved, a translucent, thick liquid, as with using MEK, or xylene?

Comment: Limonene and acetone do dissolve polystyrene.

Comment: Time to get it dissolved should depends on the batch as well as the form (foam, grains, pellets...).

Comment: Foot note: After squeezing lemon into tea in a Styrofoam cup, one's hands stick to the cup as the limonene, among other "essential oils", dissolves the polystyrene.